# Convert Excel to Yaml syntax in Python

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas, yaml

I want to convert my data that is in this form to YAML Syntax (preferably without using pandas or need to install new libraries)

Sample data in excel :

```
users | name | uid | shell

user1 | nino | 8759 | /bin/ksh

user2 | vivo | 9650 | /bin/sh
```

Desired output format :
[YAML Syntax output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqpMq.jpg)

Comment: I'm Mac OS / Ubuntu so don't touch Excel.  However `pyyaml` I use for building YAML for my Ubuntu configs interchangeably with dictionaries and lists

Comment: That's not hard to do at all even without touching `pyyaml` or Pandas. If your input file is Excel, though, you will need e.g. `xlrd` or `openpyxl` to read it; if it's e.g. CSV, you can use the built-in `csv` library. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using file operations. Since you are keen on ***"preferably without using pandas or need to install new libraries**

> Assumption : The "|" symbol is to indicate columns and is not a delimiter or separater

### Step 1

```
Save the excel file as CSV
```

Then run the code

### Code

```
# STEP 1  : Save your excel file as CSV

ctr = 0
excel_filename = "Book1.csv"
yaml_filename = excel_filename.replace('csv', 'yaml')
users = {}

with open(excel_filename, "r") as excel_csv:
    for line in excel_csv:
        if ctr == 0:
            ctr+=1  # Skip the coumn header
        else:
            # save the csv as a dictionary
            user,name,uid,shell = line.replace(' ','').strip().split(',')
            users[user] = {'name': name, 'uid': uid, 'shell': shell}



with open(yaml_filename, "w+") as yf :
    yf.write("users: \n")
    for u in users:
        yf.write(f"  {u} : \n")
        for k,v in users[u].items():
            yf.write(f"    {k} : {v}\n")
```

### Output

```
users: 
  user1 : 
    name : nino
    uid : 8759
    shell : /bin/ksh
  user2 : 
    name : vivo
    uid : 9650
    shell : /bin/sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, in your case you would just do `pd.read_excel` instead of `pd.read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='|')
df['user_col'] = 'users'
data = df.groupby('user_col')[['users', 'name','uid','shell']].apply(lambda x: x.set_index('users').to_dict(orient='index')).to_dict()
with open('newtree.yaml', "w") as f:
    yaml.dump(data, f)
```

Yaml file looks like this:

```
users:
  user1:
    name: nino
    shell: /bin/ksh
    uid: 8759
  user2:
    name: vivo
    shell: /bin/sh
    uid: 9650
```